# attached Entitlement to the case using criteria

Tags: apex

I have `Custom Metadata` where I have a record like `Entitlement Process Name`, `RecordType`, `Category`, `SubCategory`. Also I am using `Entitlement Process` and `Milestone` to calculate SLA. When I am creating an Case, I want Entitlement Process to be assign/attached to the case (on before insert) based on the RecordType, Category and SubCategory.

Note: RecordType, Category and SubCategory will be unique criteria.

I have developed below logic, what do I need to add/modified in order to attached

Do I need to update Case using DML operation ?

```
for(Case c : newCases){
            c.EntitlementId = entilementId[0];
}
```

I am getting below error because of the above condition:

```
Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger CaseTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: CaseTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Class.XXXUtil.getXXX: line 58, column 1
```

Comment: if you are using after update trigger then create a new List of cases, querying from database and then do the update, otherwise record is Readonly in after trigger. You can refer this: http://devforce.co/apex-tip-how-to-make-a-dml-operation-in-a-trigger-after-insertupdate/

Comment: Oh, I am making an used only for if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert), but still Entitlement Process is not linking. Actually Case Layout has look up to the Entitlement Process

Comment: Actually this is causing problem `for(Entitlement e : entilements ){
            entilementId.add(e.Id);
        }`

Comment: do not put entitlement lookup in Case page layout, since you are automating this through code. Design it properly, take a look into my code, debug your code properly, definitely you could solve your issue

Comment: Right, How we can bulkify the above code ?

Answer (score 1):

After retrieving the Entitilements, you should have EntitlementId.

To attach an Entitlement to a Case you need to use `EntitlementId` attribute of Case.

```
caseObj.EntitlementId = ent.id;
```

**Here is an approach to do this**

```
public void associateEntitlementToCase(List<Case> so)       
{
    //retrieve case recordtype names for each case.
    Map<Id, String> mapCaseWithRecordTypeName = new Map<Id,String>();
    Map<Id, String> mapCaseWithEntName = new Map<Id, String>();

    for(case caseObj:so)
    {
        mapCaseWithRecordTypeName.put(caseObj.Id, getRecordTypeNameById('Case',caseObj.recordTypeID));
    }

    //retrieve Entitlement Names from Custom metadata based on Case RecordType Names.
    for(Case_Setting__mdt mdtobj: [SELECT Entitlement_Name__c,
                                                          Record_Type_Name__c 
                                                   FROM Case_Setting__mdt 
                                                   where Record_Type_Name__c IN: mapCaseWithRecordTypeName.values()])
    {
        for(case caseObj:so)
        {
            //compare with case recordtype name with the recordtype name from metadata
            if(mapCaseWithRecordTypeName.get(caseObj.Id) !=null && mapCaseWithRecordTypeName.get(caseObj.Id).equalsIgnoreCase(mdtobj.Record_Type_Name__c))
            {
                mapCaseWithEntName.put(caseObj.Id,mdtobj.Entitlement_Name__c);
            }
        }
    }  


    //retrieve entitlement details based on Name and tries to match with Cases
    for(Entitlement ent : [Select name, StartDate, Id, EndDate,AccountId From Entitlement 
                            WHERE Status = 'Active' 
                            AND NAME IN: mapCaseWithEntName.values()])
    {
        for(case caseObj : so)
        {
            //compare with entitlement names and update the case
            if(mapCaseWithEntName.get(caseObj.Id)!=null && mapCaseWithEntName.get(caseObj.Id).equalsIgnoreCase(ent.name))
            {
                caseObj.EntitlementId = ent.id;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static String getRecordTypeNameById(String objectName, Id strRecordTypeId)
{
    return Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName).getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById().get(strRecordTypeId).getName();
}
```

Comment: you need to add the code later after getting entitlementId

Comment: I have given an approach to do this, feel free to change the code according to your need. You need to play with maps and lists

Comment: this is custom method to get Recordtype Name by Id. I think you should have this kind of method. And dont blindly copy paste the code, understand the logic and change that could fit your requirement

Comment: Since I have to use RecordType, Category and SubCategory, so its getting little difficult. Thanks for appraoch, but would be good if you guide with those options too

Comment: Is that my answer solved your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Entitlements don’t automatically apply to cases created using Web-to-Case, Email-to-Case, or communities. However, you can add entitlements to these features using Apex code.

```
trigger DefaultEntitlement on Case (Before Insert, Before Update) {
    List <EntitlementContact> entlContacts = [Select e.EntitlementId,e.ContactId,e.Entitlement.AssetId
                                                From EntitlementContact e
                                                Where e.ContactId in :contactIds
                                                And e.Entitlement.EndDate >= Today
                                                And e.Entitlement.StartDate <= Today];

    if(entlContacts.isEmpty()==false){
        for(Case c : Trigger.new){
            if(c.EntitlementId == null && c.ContactId != null){
                for(EntitlementContact ec:entlContacts){
                    if(ec.ContactId==c.ContactId){
                        c.EntitlementId = ec.EntitlementId;
                        if(c.AssetId==null && ec.Entitlement.AssetId!=null)
                            c.AssetId=ec.Entitlement.AssetId;

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else{
        List <Entitlement> entls = [Select e.StartDate, e.Id, e.EndDate,e.AccountId, e.AssetId
                                    From Entitlement e
                                    Where e.AccountId in :acctIds And e.EndDate >= Today
                                    And e.StartDate <= Today];

        if(entls.isEmpty()==false){
            for(Case c : Trigger.new){
                if(c.EntitlementId == null && c.AccountId != null){
                    for(Entitlement e:entls){
                        if(e.AccountId==c.AccountId){
                            c.EntitlementId = e.Id;
                            if(c.AssetId==null && e.AssetId!=null)
                                c.AssetId=e.AssetId;

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```